# IED as abbreviation and term in Cyrillic/Russian

Tags: сокращения

With a new understanding of Russian, I found this is Half Life 2. I first started wondering why they decided to use Cyrillic to write "IED", and then I began wondering if there was an abbreviation (or even a term in the first place!) for improvised explosive devices in Russian. My dictionary did not lead me far. :( Can anybody confirm what the Russian version of the abbreviation and term IED is?

[image: Interesting use of Cyrillic letters (It's upside-down. :b)]

Comment: **Й** is not **I**.  _**Й** is  **Y**.   Russian language does not have words beginning with **Й**. Exceptions are geogaphic names (York, Yellowstone) and **йогурт** (yogurt). Accordingly, the Russian abbreviation cannot have **Й**.

Comment: The inscription is not valid: Д and Й are upside-down, but even if we assume the camera is upside-down and turn the image 180 deg, we get inverted (left-right) letter E, which is not a meaningful symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Russian Wikipedia article cross-linked with the English Wikipedia "Improvised Explosive Device" article via the "Languages" list is [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Самодельное_взрывное_устройство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) or СВУ.

The letters in your image would have to be mirror-image flipped vertically to form valid Cyrillic letters, and then you get ДЕЙ, which doesn't mean anything in particular.